# What happens if you use teeth-whitening strips too often?

Tags: dentistry, lasting-effects-duration, risks, bleach-teeth-whitening, white-strips-teeth

Most whitening strips instruct the user to apply them only once every 6 months.  What negative effects could occur if I used them once every 4 months instead?

Comment: https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/721/43